# How to make QPolarChart angular axis counterclockwise?

Tags: qt, plot, draw, qwidget, qchart

By default QPolarChart has clockwise angular axis:
[image]

I need to make phasor diagram widget, but on phasor diagrams angles must go counterclockwise, phasors must rotate like that:
[image]

I didn't find method to do this in Qt docs. How can I do it?